# FATAL: could not access private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ssl

This is what I enter:

```
user@user-computer:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin$ ./postgres -D /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/
```

This is what I get:

```
[4173-1] FATAL:  could not access private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": Permission denied
```

Can anyone help me? should I change permissions on ss-cert...key file?

Comment: If you don't like the way I ask the question,  please tell me how to change it or what is wrong about it so I can improve the question; instead of just giving me a minus 1... that doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happens because you're trying to launch PostgreSQL as your own unpriviledged user, and it's not meant to run like that.

Ubuntu provides PostgreSQL packaged in a way that it should be launched  with:

```
 $ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
 #   or
 $ sudo service postgresql start
```

or for finer-grained control with `pg_ctlcluster`, see
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pg_ctlcluster.8.html

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the problem, but unfortunately not the only problem, after I tried your solution I got a different error: "chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/run/postgresql’: Operation not permitted". So I decided to completely reinstall my postgresql instance and followed the instructions in to this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110927/would-you-recommend-postgresql-over-mysql And after this your solution worked :) thnx.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the `postgres` user doesnt belong to `ssl-cert` usergroup 
Try adding `postgres` user to the group `ssl-cert`

make sure that `postgres` is the owner of `/var/lib/postgresql/version_no/main`
eg: `sudo chown postgres -R /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/`

Run the below code to fix the usergroup issue and fixing the permissions

```
# > It happened to me and it turned out that I removed erroneously the postgres user from "ssl-cert" group, set it back with
sudo gpasswd -a postgres ssl-cert

# Fixed ownership and mode
sudo chown root:ssl-cert  /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
sudo chmod 740 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

# now postgresql starts! (and install command doesn't fail anymore)
sudo service postgres restart

#also try running pg_ctlcluster <version> <cluster> <action>
sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.6 main start
```

[courtsey](https://gist.github.com/GabLeRoux/0c60f9be0c28b6b41f64cb55474b0ccb) to GabLeRoux

Answer (score 0):

*(In addition to the existing 2 answers)*

Permissions should be set properly for the directory as well
*(where the `ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` file resides in i.e., `/etc/ssl/private`).*

Note: The execute (x) permission is required in the parent directories, to traverse the directories leading up to the file.

This is what worked for me:

```
chmod 640 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
chmod 755 /etc/ssl/private
```

Depending on the owner and group, the permissions can be updated accordingly. (Keep in mind that, `postgres` may not be the only application/service that will be accessing this particular folder)

- If the `/etc/ssl/private` folder belongs to the group `ssl-cert` and owner `root`, then, the permissions for that folder can be like this: `drwx--x---`
- If the `/etc/ssl/private` folder belongs to the group `root` and owner `root`, then, the permissions for that folder can be like this: `drwxr-xr-x`